# Cyclotomic field automorphisms "fill up" $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: galois-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials

I know from reading that the Galois group of a cyclotomic polynomial is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$. While I believe this, I can't figure out why that should work. In particular, it's not obvious to me that all of the available permutations of the roots should actually extend to automorphisms, because the way that we think of the action $\overline{m}\cdot\zeta^k=\zeta^{mk}$ is not bijective over the whole field and in any case it does not fix $\mathbb{Q}$.

Are there explicit expressions of the automorphisms that look pretty, or do we generally argue their existence in some other way?

(Tagged homework because I am trying to get an insight into a problem on an outstanding assignment in my class)

Comment: The action of $\overline{m}$ is extended linearly. In other words:
$$\overline{m}\cdot\sum_kq_k\zeta^k=\sum_kq_k\zeta^{mk},$$ where $k$ is an integer and $q_k$ are rational numbers. This is bijective.

Comment: But it is not an answer, because proving that this gives an automorphism is quite a task unless you know suitable results from field theory in general and cyclotomic polynomials in particular.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I don't follow. The question asks for a canonical automorphism for every element in $(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^*$, building from a specific action of the group on the roots. Given your hint, once you view the field as a $\mathbb{Q}$ vector space (with the roots forming a spanning set) and you already have that action, isn't it just a small calculation to show that the action respects the additive and multiplicative structures?

Comment: If you know from elsewhere that the roots of the cyclotomic polynomial are precisely $\zeta^m$, $\gcd(m,n)=1$, then yeah.

Answer (score 2):

Every automorphism is completely determined by where $\zeta$ is sent to. $\zeta$ can be sent to any other primitive $n$th root of unity by the very basics of field theory (any other root of the $n$th cyclotomic polynomial). So any automorphism is determined by some $k$ where $\zeta \rightarrow \zeta^k$, where $(k,n)=1$ and the isomorphism between the galois group and $(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^*$ should be clear.

Comment: It is "the very basics of field theory" that this question is about. I have a reasonable understanding of the group-theoretic aspects and the rest of the argument makes sense. More than that, it's clear to me that there is a group automorphism from $\zeta\to\zeta^k$ when $k,n$ are coprime. What had hung me up was that you can't just treat this function as a power function and expect to extend that to a field automorphism.

Comment: Any isomorphism of fields extends to an isomorphism of splitting fields, and if $a,b$ are roots of some irreducible polynomial over $k$ there is a isomorphism $k(a) \rightarrow  k(b)$ such that $a \rightarrow b$. I would hope that anyone attempting Galois theory would have seen these results before.

Comment: At the time this answer was posted, I found this comment to be very dismissive and was honestly quite hurt by it. Several diplomas later, the emotion has faded, but I still find it to be very dismissive. This is not a useful tone to take with a student, particularly a student whose background you do not know. (I don't mean to dunk on PVAL personally, as I'm sure they too have grown in the last 7+ years. I just want to say to any students who come across this question that it's okay to ask for a kinder tone from your professors and tutors— they should know better)